# Bootstrap 4 full-height card with independent scrollable columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a card that will function as a chat body and therefore take the full height of the screen as nothing else will be displayed besides the chat body and I want it to occupy all the space on the screen.
In the card, I have two columns need to be both independently scrollable. So I don't want the website to be scrollable, but the two columns inside the card.
First column is for the actual chat, the second one is for a list of chatting users.

While I got it to work with setting hardcoded max-height values by pixels, I cannot seem to get it working with the automatic full screen height.

What happens is the card is being rendered as full height, but the content overflows the card despite having an `overflow-y: auto`, when setting the overflow to scroll it basically makes an scrollbar the exact height of the content.

Code:

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-header">
      100% Height card
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
          <div style="overflow-y: scroll;" class="mh-100">
           Independent scrollable column<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <div stlye="overflow-y: auto" class="mh-100">
            Independent scrollable column #2
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
            Text<br>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for now I went for calculating the max-height in jQuery as it's fairly simple and allows me to put any content I desire without worrying about changing the height percentages:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    calculateHeight();
    $(window).resize(function() { calculateHeight() });
});

function calculateHeight()
{
    let wnHeight = $(window).height();
    let boxHeight = $("#messagesBox").height();
    let cardHeight = $("#messagesCard").outerHeight();
    let cardPos = $("#messagesCard").offset();
    // calculate the offset to the bottom, this is how much we need to expand (or shrink)
    let offset = boxHeight + (wnHeight - (cardHeight + cardPos.top));
    if(offset < 480) // this just prevents the card from getting too small
        offset = 480;
    $("#messagesBox").css('max-height', `${offset}px`);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be harder than I initially thought, I have found a few examples of doing similar things with flexbox, however they don't work in my case because I also have a navigation bar above the container. I want the card to fill all the remaining height without creating any overflow. As for now I went for manual max-height calculation in jQuery, but it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made an example of how to approach this using [FLEX](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) and [SIZING](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) utilities from `Bootstrap 4`. First, with `CSS`, we divide the total **view-port height** between the **card-header** and **card-body** (15% to header and 85% to body). Second, we use **w-*** classes in replacement of **col-*** for the body-width division, with **d-flex** class applied to the body. Third, and just to keep `html` markup simple, we fill the containers from `JQuery`. Hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Fill the message and friend containers.

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        $("#msgWrap").append("<div class='text-primary'>Message " + i + "</div>");
        $("#friendWrap").append("<div class='text-danger'>Friend " + i + "</div>");
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.card-header {
    max-height: 15vh;
}

.card-body {
    max-height: 85vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center text-white bg-dark">
      <span class="mx-auto">100% Height card</span>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body d-flex">
      <div id="msgCol" class="d-flex flex-column w-75">
         <div id="msgWrap" class="w-100" style="overflow-y:scroll"></div>
         <input class="w-100" type="text" placeholder="Write a new message"/>
      </div>

      <div id="friendCol" class="d-flex flex-column w-25">
        <div id="friendWrap" class="w-100" style="overflow-y:scroll"></div>
        <div class="w-100 border border-primary text-center text-bold">
          FOOTER
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But what if I'd want to add some other elements such as an navbar or a input field under the scroll box? It looks like I'd need to alter the heights manually. And I see that wrapping the divs in a column or a row destroys everything. I guess I'll just stick with calculating the height via jQuery. It only calculates the distance from the bottom of the page to the card and adds that distance to the scrolling div's 'max-height' property

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for now, but i update the answer to include some elements at the bottom of each scroll container, no height on the CSS was changed, just used Bootstrap classes (d-flex, flex-column, w-*).